# How can I show the polygon coordinates by popup in Angular?

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet.draw, ngx-leaflet, ngx-leaflet-draw

here is the function of drawing polygon in leaflet map.

```
onDrawCreated(e: any) {
        const { layerType, layer } = e;
        if (layerType === "polygon") {
            const polygonCoordinates = layer._latlngs;
            console.log(polygonCoordinates);


        }
        this.drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
    }
```

And here the polygonCoordinates;

```
 Array(1)
    0
    : 
    Array(4)
    0
    : 
    LatLng {lat: 54.23955053156179, lng: -112.10449218750001}
    1
    : 
    LatLng {lat: 50.064191736659104, lng: -108.4130859375}
    2
    : 
    LatLng {lat: 48.19538740833338, lng: -116.80664062500001}
    3
    : 
    LatLng {lat: 52.07950600379697, lng: -115.66406250000001}
    length
    : 
    4
    [[Prototype]]
    : 
    Array(0)
    length
    : 
    1
    [[Prototype]]
    : 
    Array(0)
```

How can I show this coordinates on function with popup?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. One way is to build an array that will contain all the `lat lngs` and then join them inside the popup in order to visualize them. Then using polygon's `bindPopup` and `openPopup` methods you can display them.

```
onDrawCreated(e: any) {
    const { layerType, layer } = e;
    if (layerType === "polygon") {
      const polygonCoordinates = layer._latlngs;
      console.log(polygonCoordinates);

      const allCoordsInOneArray = [];
      polygonCoordinates[0].forEach((item) => {
        allCoordsInOneArray.push(item.lat.toFixed(2));
        allCoordsInOneArray.push(item.lng.toFixed(2));
      });
      console.log(allCoordsInOneArray);
      layer
        .bindPopup(`Polygon coordinates are ${allCoordsInOneArray.join(", ")}`)
        .openPopup();
    }
    this.drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-show-the-polygon-coordinates-by-popup-in-angular-tz3d7r?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:925-1517)

Normally the popup should auto trigger once you form the polygon. If it does not simply click the polygon and you will get it open.